# iPad issue with a modal view: modal view label null after view controller is created

Tags: iphone, ipad, delegates, ios

This is a weird issue.  I have created a view controller with a nib file for my modal view.  On that view there is a label, number and text view.  When I create the view from the source view, I tried to set the label, but it shows that the label is `null (0x0)`.  Kinda weird... Any suggestions?  Now lets look at the code (I put all of the code here because that shows more than I can just explain):

The modal view controller - in IB the label is connected to the UILabel object:

```
    @implementation ModalViewController

@synthesize delegate;
@synthesize goalLabel, goalText, goalNumber;

// Done button clicked
- (void)dismissView:(id)sender {

    // Call the delegate to dismiss the modal view
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didDismissModalView: newText:)]) {

        NSNumber *tmpNum = goalNumber;
        NSString *tmpString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[goalText text]];
        [delegate didDismissModalView:tmpNum newText:tmpString];

        [tmpNum release];
        [tmpString release];
    }
}

- (void)cancelView:(id)sender {

    // Call the delegate to dismiss the modal view
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didCancelModalView)])
        [delegate didCancelModalView];
}

-(void) setLabelText:(NSString *)text {
    [goalLabel setText:text];
}

/*
 // The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    // bring up the keyboard....
    [goalText becomeFirstResponder];
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // set the current goal number to -1 so we know none was set
    goalNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: -1];

    // Override the right button to show a Done button
    // which is used to dismiss the modal view
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                               target:self
                                               action:@selector(dismissView:)] autorelease];

    // and now for the cancel button
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                               target:self
                                              action:@selector(cancelView:)] autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Add/Update Goals";
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Overriden to allow any orientation.
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

And here is where the view controller is created, variables set, and displayed:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // put a checkmark....
    UITableViewCell *tmpCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [tmpCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];

    // this is where the popup is gonna popup!
    // ===> HEre We Go!

    // Create the modal view controller
    ModalViewController *mdvc = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ModalDetailView" bundle:nil];

    // We are the delegate responsible for dismissing the modal view 
    [mdvc setDelegate:self];

    // Create a Navigation controller
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                             initWithRootViewController:mdvc];

    // set the modal view type
    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    // set the label for all of the goals....
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Long Term Goal 1:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Long Term Goal 2:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 2) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Long Term Goal 3:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3]];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 3) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Long Term Goal 4:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]];
    }


    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Short Term Goal 1:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Short Term Goal 2:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6]];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 2) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Short Term Goal 3:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 3) {
        [mdvc setLabelText:[[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Short Term Goal 4:"] autorelease]];
        [mdvc setGoalNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:8]];
    }

    // show the navigation controller modally
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    // Clean up resources
    [navController release];
    [mdvc release];

    // ==> Ah... we are done...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face!

Here is what I did:

Added a new function to the delegate

```
@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
    - (void)didDismissModalView:(NSNumber *)goalNbr newText:(NSString *)textToSave;
    - (void)didCancelModalView;
    - (void)willShow:(id)theView;
@end
```

In the `viewWillAppear` function, I added the following:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(willShow:)])
    [delegate willShow:self];
```

This allows full access to the modal view that is going to show, so we are able to change the label, text box and variables within the active modal view.

```
- (void)willShow:(ModalViewController *)theView {

    [theView.goalLabel setText:labelText];
    [theView setGoalNumber:goalNumber];
    [theView.goalText setText:goalText];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness' sake, in the event anyone else stumbles on this (it helped me)...

The modal view controller's interface needs to define a variable to hold the delegate:

```
@protocol ReminderPhotoViewDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)willShow:(id)theView;
@end
@interface ReminderPhotoViewController : UIViewController {
    id<ReminderPhotoViewDelegate> delegate;
    UIImageView *reminderImage;
    UILabel *reminderLabel;
}
@property (assign) id<ReminderPhotoViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *reminderImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *reminderLabel;
@end
```

Within the implementation of the modal controller, be sure to synthesize those properties:

```
@implementation ReminderPhotoViewController
@synthesize reminderImage, reminderLabel;
@synthesize delegate;
```

Whatever your "calling" controller is must declare support for this protocol in its own implementation:

```
#import "ReminderPhotoViewController.h"
@interface ReminderViewController : UIViewController <ReminderPhotoViewDelegate> {
}
```

Finally, when you create the instance of your modal controller, you need to set the calling class to be its delegate:

```
ReminderPhotoViewController *photo = [[ReminderPhotoViewController alloc] init];
[photo setDelegate:self];
```

That's a more complete set of declarations and code - it's exactly what the answer shows, just with more of the supporting code.

Then, as noted above, your calling controller adds the method from the protocol:

```
- (void)willShow:(ReminderPhotoViewController *)theView {
    theView.reminderImage.image = selectedImage;
    theView.reminderLabel.text = selectedText;
}
```